# Finder search file not working, but Spotlight able to find the file

Tags: finder, search, ventura

My macOS Ventura can't search any file in the Finder (top right).

I already add the folder in System Preference -> Spotlight (added) User folder.

My Spotlight can search by filename, but Finder top right text search is always no result.

I did select the "This Mac", it does search, but not the result file (other system file.

I downloaded a filename "invoice.pdf", i can't search the file when select "Downloads", but I click "This Mac" also no result show up.

File is inside Downloads Folder:
[image]

When I search in the top right: invoice (no result)
[image]

When I search "This Mac"
[image]

I also notice "Recent" always empty.
[image]

How can I index all the file and make my Finder search work again.
Looking for: **I want to use Finder search instead of Spotlight.**

**Update:**

I followed AVelj Solution, but still the same result.

Here is the output:
[image]

What is the reason?

Comment: Finder search is using Spotlight.

Comment: It does not work. Now I use `Path Finder` to search File, not idea why Finder still not working.

Comment: Alright, thx for explaining.

Comment: Same issue. Spotlight search works instantly, Finder only shows results when "This Mac" is selected. Searching within *any* folder shows no results.

Comment: @DerekJones please follow the solution step by step. especially Step3, please remove it.

Comment: Thanks @Shiro, I just wanted to add a comment to help make this more discoverable for others. It took me quite some time playing with search terms for this to finally show up in the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

macOS Finder uses Spotlight. By default all files are indexed automatically.

1. Make sure ALL checkboxes are enabled in System Preferences → Siri & Spotlight → **Search results**
2. To force and rebuild the Spotlight index, click the **Spotlight Privacy** button. Add your user folder (~username) to the list of locations.

[image: Add user folder to macos Spotlight to prevent from searching.]

3. Now, **REMOVE** your previously added user folder and any folders that show up in the privacy list which is prevent Spotlight from searching. Click **Done** and Spotlight will reindex your user folder.

Indexing may can take some time. Usually files will show in a couple of minutes in the Spotlight search and macOS Finder. Keep your mac running.

4. Also, open Finder Preferences → Advanced → When performing a search select **Search the current folder**

Comment: As I mention, in the spotlight it is able to search the file, but my goal is using Finder, not Spotlight. The folder I had added to the privacy, so spotlight is working well. Just Finder is not working.

Comment: @Shiro Does it find the file when you change to "Search the current folder" in the Finder Preferences → Advanced → When performing a search?

Comment: As I check my Finder Preferences → Advanced → When performing a search: It is set as "Search the current folder".

Comment: @Shiro: Did you reindex your user folder as described?

Comment: yes, I did remove all the folder in Spotlight Privacy, then add user folder again, still the same.

Comment: @Shiro What happens when you rename the PDF file? Are you able to find files with different file types?

Comment: the file rename before and after also can't be found. Finder the index is not working. any command can be reindex

Comment: What do you mean by "any command can be reindex" Are you able to find files with different file types using macOS finder search and Spotlight? Did you try to completely reindex  your system volume? Otherwise something is totally wrong with your system.

Comment: I actually explained yesterday in another question on how to reindex spotlight using the command line, so you might want to look at my answer there: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457049/362111 Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @AVelj, I did try your step. It still does not work in Finder Search, my spotlight search is working fine. It was working fine as well previous. My goal is want to search file in Finder which make more sense to find particular file in a folder

Comment: Today I read carefully the instruction. I only notice the drag to privacy folder is to prevent to search. I uncheck all the checkbox, and drag and check all and remove the it. In the spotlight finally I can see the Index Progress Bar. The search is working now.